# Pass a list of inheriting objects to a function that accepts a list of father objects

Tags: c++, inheritance, stdlist

I have a class that inherits from another class:

```
class A {
    //...
};

class B : public A {
    //...
};
```

I have a function that accepts a (const) list of pointers to the father type:

```
void foo(const list<A*>& myList);
```

I want to pass to that function a list that contains pointers to the child type:

```
list<B*> myList;
//populate list
foo(myList);
```

I get a compilation error:

> error C2664: cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::list<_Ty>' to 'const std::list<_Ty> &'

I wasn't able to cast it with either C style casting, nor with `reinterpret_cast`:

```
foo(reinterpret_cast<list<A*> >(myList));
```

Gives the error

> error C2440: 'reinterpret_cast' : cannot convert from 'std::list<_Ty>' to 'std::list<_Ty>'

```
foo((list<A*>)myList);
```

Gives the error

> error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'std::list<_Ty>' to 'std::list<_Ty>'

One solution for this would be to implement `foo` for `list<B*>` and 'list`(`C`is another type that inherits from`A`), but that would be a less elegant solution. Is there a way to pass a list of inheriting objects as a list of objects of the father type?

Comment: No, don't do dynamic cast. It will not work. It's a waste of time. The short answer here is: no, C++ does not work this way.

Comment: I assume you meant `class B : public A`?

Comment: None of the linked questions seem to explain how do it correctly. i.e write a function that can operate on collection of derived classes. Answer here: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/MQwzHu

Comment: Improved example: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/yvklII